# how do I remove /etc/profile.d from gitbash command prompt in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-bash

[Picture of my command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38TR9.png)

Is there any way to remove the `/etc/profile.d` text in the gitbash prompt in vscode?

It currently shows:

```
/etc/profile.d
$
```

Here is my git-prompt.sh file

```
if test -f /etc/profile.d/git-sdk.sh
then
    TITLEPREFIX=SDK-${MSYSTEM#MINGW}
else
    TITLEPREFIX=$MSYSTEM
fi

if test -f ~/.config/git/git-prompt.sh
then
    . ~/.config/git/git-prompt.sh
else
    PS1='\[\033]0;$TITLEPREFIX:$PWD\007\]' # set window title
    PS1="$PS1"'\n'                 # new line
    PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[32m\]'       # change to green
    # PS1="$PS1"'\u@\h '             # user@host<space>
    # PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[35m\]'       # change to purple
    # PS1="$PS1"'$MSYSTEM '          # show MSYSTEM
    # PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[33m\]'       # change to brownish yellow
    PS1="$PS1"'\w'                 # current working directory
    if test -z "$WINELOADERNOEXEC"
    then
        GIT_EXEC_PATH="$(git --exec-path 2>/dev/null)"
        COMPLETION_PATH="${GIT_EXEC_PATH%/libexec/git-core}"
        COMPLETION_PATH="${COMPLETION_PATH%/lib/git-core}"
        COMPLETION_PATH="$COMPLETION_PATH/share/git/completion"
        if test -f "$COMPLETION_PATH/git-prompt.sh"
        then
            . "$COMPLETION_PATH/git-completion.bash"
            . "$COMPLETION_PATH/git-prompt.sh"
            PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[36m\]'  # change color to cyan
            PS1="$PS1"'`__git_ps1`'   # bash function
        fi
    fi
    PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[0m\]'        # change color
    PS1="$PS1"'\n'                 # new line
    PS1="$PS1"'$ '                 # prompt: always $
fi

MSYS2_PS1="$PS1"               # for detection by MSYS2 SDK's bash.basrc

# Evaluate all user-specific Bash completion scripts (if any)
if test -z "$WINELOADERNOEXEC"
then
    for c in "$HOME"/bash_completion.d/*.bash
    do
        # Handle absence of any scripts (or the folder) gracefully
        test ! -f "$c" ||
        . "$c"
    done
fi
```

thanks!

Comment: is that not just your prompt showing your current directory? what do you see when you change to a different directory?

Answer (score 0):

The `PS1="$PS1"'\w'` is supposed to display the working directory, so you might need to remove that if `/etc/profile.d` does represent your current folder you are in.

Double-check also your other shell configuration file:

- both system ones `/etc/bashrc` or `/etc/bash.bashrc`, assuming a bash session
- or the user ones (`.bashrc` or `.profile`)